Working with very large GeoTIFFs using QGIS
I would like to ask for advice on working with very large GeoTIFFs.
I have downloaded several large GeoTIFFs, then I load them into QGIS and combine them into a virtual raster.
Since I need the GeoTIFF at a lower resolution, I export the GeoTIFF at the desired resolution and get one 200GB GeoTIFF. I don't create smaller parts because I need to process it afterwards (it is an island and I need a smooth transition to a transparent background just off the coast). I'll upload it to gimp and crop it there to create the transition to the transparent background. From gimp I export it in BigTIFF format with coordinates and reload it into QGIS.
And this is where the problem arises. The GeoTIFF is loaded correctly, the coordinates match, but nothing is displayed, it just keeps loading. If I zoom in to 100% magnification, the small area shows up, when zooming out again nothing. I tried letting it load for about 2 days and still nothing. CPU loaded with QGIS at 60% and disk read also ran all the time and but did not load to display. with the original exported GeoTIFF there is no problem, size-wise they are the same.
Subsequently, I need to create a GeoTIFF 2048x2048 from this large one. If I create a tile via GDAL, it writes me destitis thousand minutes and the same when exporting.
How do I work with this file to make it work faster?
The first exported 200gb GeoTIFF loads and displays normally and creating tiles only takes a couple of hours.

You probably broke it in gimp as it doesn't know about geoTiffs. Remember that compression is your friend when working with tiffs
